# Why is the transform in Schönhage–Strassen's multiplication algorithm cheap?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, multiplication

The [Schönhage–Strassen multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) algorithm works by turning multiplications of size $N$ into many multiplications of size $lg(N)$ with a number-theoretic transform, and recursing. At least I think that's what it does because there's some other cleverness and I really don't understand it well enough to summarize accurately. It finishes in $O(N \cdot  lg(N) \cdot lg(lg(N)))$ time.

A number-theoretic transform is exactly like a [Discrete Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), except it's done in the finite field $F_{2^N+1}$ of integers modulo $2^N+1$. This makes the operations a lot cheaper, since the Fourier transform has a lot of multiplying by roots of unity, and $F_{2^N+1}$'s roots of unity are all powers of 2 so we can just shift! Also, integers are a lot easier to work with than floating point complex numbers.

Anyways, the thing that confuses me is that $F_{2^N+1}$ is very large. If I give you a random element from $F_{2^N+1}$, it takes $O(N)$ bits to specify it. So adding two elements should take $O(N)$ time. And the DFT does a *lot* of adding.

Schönhage–Strassen splits the input into $\frac{N}{lg(N)}$ groups with $lg(N)$ bits. These groups are the values of $F_{2^N+1}$ that it will transform. Each pass of the DFT will have $O(\frac{N}{lg(N)})$ additions/subtractions, and there are $O(lg(\frac{N}{lg(N)}))$ passes. So based on addition taking $O(N)$ time it seems like the cost of all those additions should be $O(N \frac{N}{lg(N)} lg(\frac{N}{lg(N)}))$, which is asymptotically the same as $O(N^2)$.

We can do a bit better than that... because the values start out so small, the additions are quite sparse. The first pass' additions really only cost $O(lg(N))$ each, and the second pass' cost $2^1 O(lg(N))$ each, and the i'th pass' cost $O(min(N, 2^i \cdot lg(N)))$ each, but that still all totals out to a terrible $\frac{N^2}{lg(N)}$.

**How is Schönhage–Strassen making the additions cheap? How much do they cost overall?**

Is it because the algorithm actually uses $F_{N+1}$ (with $N$ guaranteed to be a power of 2)? There's enough stacked $2^{2^{n}}$ and german in the [paper](http://moonflare.com/misc/Schnelle%20Multiplikation%20gro%DFer%20Zahlen.html) that I'm really not sure. On the other hand, I don't think that guarantees enough roots of unity for things to work out.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article? At the very least, it's not in German. According to Wikipedia, the size is reduced from $N$ to $n \approx \sqrt{N}$ at each step, which works out since then $n^2 = \Theta(N)$.

Comment: @Yuval Where do you see $n \approx \sqrt{N}$ in the article? There's a lot of "primitive root", and an extra optimization trick involving square roots, but otherwise I don't see it. I do see "Split each input number into vectors X and Y of $2^k$ parts each, where $2^k$ divides N.", but no definition of $k$.

Comment: @Yuval That does seem to help... but there's still $O(\sqrt{N})$ additions per pass with each costing $O(N)$. So a pass costs $O(N^{\frac{3}{2}})$, which is better but not good enough.

Comment: The setting of $k$ appears in the sentence "The optimal number of pieces to divide the input into is proportional to $\sqrt{N}$." The value of $n$ is then $2^{\Theta(\sqrt{N})}+1$, so each addition costs $O(\sqrt{N})$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm#Overview), at each step the length of the integers is reduced from $N$ to (roughly) $\sqrt{N}$, and there are (roughly) $\sqrt{N}$ of them, and so the additions only cost $O(N)$. There is a detailed analysis of the running time in the final paragraph of the linked section, copied here in case it changes:

In the recursive step, the observation is used that:

- Each element of the input vectors has at most $N/2^k$ bits;
- The product of any two input vector elements has at most $2N/2^k$ bits;
- Each element of the convolution is the sum of at most $2^k$ such products, and so cannot exceed $2N/2^k + k$ bits.

Here $N$ is current input length and $k = \Theta(\sqrt{N})$. Arithmetic is done modulo $2^n+1$, where $n$ is some multiple of $2^k$ which is larger than $2N/2^k + k$; note that $n = \Theta(\sqrt{N})$.

Comment: I don't understand why each element of the convolution can't exceed $\frac{2N}{2^k} + k$ bits. I understand that if we just added them together without any shifting that they would be no larger than that, but aren't we doing arithmetic in $F_{2^N+1}$ and scaling things by huge powers of 2? The $\sqrt{N}$'th element of the convolution is $\sum_{i=0}^{\sqrt{N}} x_i 2^{i \sqrt{N}}$, stepping up the power by $\sqrt{N}$ for each element, so won't it fail to benefit from overlapping their bits at all and require $N$ bits?

Comment: Are the additions being doing in $F_{2^N+1}$? The article says "it's necessary to use a smaller N for recursive multiplications", but it's not clear if that step down is done for both the transform and the pointwise multiplications or only for the pointwise multiplications.

Comment: The Wikipedia article mixes up $N$ and $n$; hopefully that's fixed in my revised answer. Arithmetic is done modulo $2^n+1$, where $n = \Theta(\sqrt{N})$. The resulting vector can then be combined to give a result modulo $2^N+1$.

Comment: Reiterating, the trick is to perform arithmetic modulo a smaller modulus, whose size is compatible with the size of the pieces. The $N$-bit integers are cut into roughly $\sqrt{N}$ pieces of length $\sqrt{N}$ bits.

Comment: Ah, that explains it then. That would mean the $lg(n)$ version is also quite fast, since it has $lg(n)$ sized operations. If you could explicitly say that in your answer, that'd be great.

Answer (score 3):

There's an excellent explanation of exactly what's going on, including how the size of the field goes down as you progress, in GMP's documentation: [15.1.6 FFT Multiplication](https://gmplib.org/manual/FFT-Multiplication.html#FFT-Multiplication).

A more theoretically in-depth overview starts on page 55 of [Modern Computer Arithmetic (pdf)](http://www.loria.fr/~zimmerma/mca/mca-cup-0.5.9.pdf) (well... the browser says page 71 but the page itself says 55). It explains the algorithm's correctness and breaks down the complexity analysis.